# How to connect to hotel WiFi

Tags: wireless, login

Wireless issue/hotel WiFi.  NIC Realtek RRL8111/8168/8411 PCI in an Inspiron 3501 running 22.04.3 LTS I constantly travel.  Until two days ago to login my laptop on a hotel network I would bring up Firefox and it would prompt me to go to the network login page and I would simply login. It no longer does this.  I cannot connect with any browser via WiFi. Signal is good, phone connects, just not laptop .  I'm tethering to connect. It seems something changed   Followed troubleshooting from FAQ, nothing has worked.

Comment: Connect to the network, then try to go to google.com or some other well-known site. If it requires you to log in it should redirect you to the login page.

Comment: The device you list is ethernet please edit to include results from terminal for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; lsusb; rfkill list`

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.